# eclipse drag editor tabs to re-arrange them

Tags: eclipse

My previous install of Eclipse allowed me to drag editor tabs to re-arrange their ordering. For example, if I cloned an editor window and the new tab appeared at the end of the tab row I could drag it to be next to the tab I cloned it from.

I don't know if the ability to drag tabs in my previous install was from a plugin or other modification I installed. To sum up, if I have editor tabs in the order:

TAB-a TAB-b TAB-c

I would like to be able to drag the editor tabs to re-order them:

TAB-a TAB-c TAB-b

I am using Eclipse 4.8, Photon, installed in the past week.

NOTE:
See comment below: it works now, but I don't know what I did to make it work

Comment: This still works on Eclipse Photon (4.8). You don't get much feedback from the UI just a vertical gray bar between tabs showing where the drop will be.

Comment: All I am getting, using Photon (4.8), is a circle with a diagonal line through it, i.e. a not-allowed symbol. I don't get the small vertical line indicating that I can drop a dragged tab. I got that on my previous installation though.

Comment: All right. I have no idea why it is working now. Before, as I mentioned above, I got the circle with a line through it, indicating that re-arranging in the same group was not allowed. Now I get the subtle line as I drag, indicating that I can drop the tab in a new position. I don't know why it works now but I will not complain.